# Maven build jar with dependencies outside runnable jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I am developing a Spring Boot Application with Maven. When I run Maven Install it compiles all dependencies inside the Runnable Jar file and classpath.idx file shows that it is referencing to the dependencies packaged inside the runnable Jar.

However, I do not want my runnable jar to contain any library file. Like Eclipse's option to "Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR", I need it for maven as well.

I tried implementing the assembly feature but that only copies all required files but keeps maintains and references all jar files from inside the runnable jar.

pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <groupId>custom</groupId>
                        <artifactId>another.custom.app</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <file>${basedir}/custom_libs/another.custom.app.jar</file>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly:package</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>my.current.app.Application</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and the assembly file I am using is
assembly.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly>
    <id>package</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>


    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
            
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>


    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <!-- maping the dependencies jar names. NOTICE : if you used this definition, 
                you need to use customClasspathLayout classPath configuration for the maven-jar-plugin 
                in the pomg -->
            <outputFileNameMapping>
                ${artifact.groupId}.${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}
            </outputFileNameMapping>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

</assembly>
```

This just creates a libs folder with all library jars, next to the runnable Jar. Main runnable Jar still contains all libs, and classpath.idx file shows that links are still the same.

[image]

What do I do to build Runnable Jar without dependencies and all dependencies should go under a library folder next to the Runnable jar and classpath should use that path.

Comment: If you are developing a spring boot app the question is: Why do you use maven-assembly-plugin, and why using maven-jar-plugin and maven-install-plugin ? Use spring-boot-maven-plugin that's it...

Comment: Generally you shouldn't be doing that, as it will lead to more problems than it solves. If you really want to change the output format take a look at the [Spring Boot Thin Launcher](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher#spring-boot-thin-launcher-) project.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for pointing that out, I have not used maven extensively so had little knowledge there. By simply using spring-boot-maven-plugin, it packages a default jar with dependencies packaged inside. How do I fulfill the requirement using spring-boot-maven-plugin?